# htaccess reserved words?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with `.htaccess`. I'm doing something like this:

```
# Ofertas
Rewriterule ^offers/$ offers.php [QSA,L]
Rewriterule ^offers/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]*)/$ offers.php?idcat=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]

# Entrega
Rewriterule ^delivery/$ delivery.php [QSA,L]
Rewriterule ^delivery/([0-9]*)/([0-9a-zA-Z\-]*)/$ delivery.php?idcat=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]
```

It does not work but if such changes or special offers by offerslist-offers delivery functions and the same thing happens if I change to deliverysend works. Is there any restriction of words in htaccess?

Comment: Are `Ofertas` / `Entraga` comments? This surely isn't a keyword and would lead to errors.

Comment: As i write i did not put the # but if in the htaccess

Comment: I'm sorry, that makes little sense. My interpretation is that you *didn't* prefix "Ofertas" or "Entraga" with a hash mark (`#`) in order to comment them. This might still be the source of the error. Other than that, you might want to elaborate more...

Comment: I just delete all the comments to see if anything was wrong but does not work, if for example i use htaccess works delivery is rare but if the delivery to delivery2 various works, I'm not using any framework or cms.
pastebin.com/V6WgbsGQ

Answer (score 0):

Apache probably has multiviews enabled. Try disabling it with `options -multiviews`.